# south migrate OperationalError in backend: no such column: myModel.myField

Tags: python, django, django-south, migrate

I'm using Django 1.6 ,sqlite3 and South 1.0.1 for migrating the models.
I have a table `myTable`and I'd like to add a column(field) in this table.
So I add this field `myField` in the `model.py`.
Then I run:

```
sudo python manage.py schemamigration myApp --auto
python manage.py migrate myApp
```

It occurs an error: `XXX table already exist`

**XXX table** is my first table in myApp, OK so I run

```
python manage.py migrate myApp --fake
```

Here comes the result:

```
Running migrations for myApp:
- Migrating forwards to 0008_auto__add_field_myTable_myField
> myModel:0008_auto__add_field_myTable_myField
   (faked)
```

It seems no error, but when I enter the 127.0.0.1/admin/myApp/myTable, there comes the error:

```
OperationalError in myApp:no such column: myTable.myField
```

But I looked at the tables with the command:

```
sudo python manage.py sqlall myApp
```

The `myField` exist in `myTable`!

I don't know how to fix that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ops, I find out why...just add

```
sudo python manage.py schemamigration myApp --auto
python manage.py migrate myApp --fake
```

before do the add column.